# Circuit diagram for running bipolar stepper motor using LDR

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor

I am new to Arduino, some how I have put this code together to run stepper motor using LDR(kind of solar tracker program) I searched on net and tried using servo motor circuit to run stepper motor, assuming just replacing servo motor with stepper motor would work. I guess that is not the case (because servo motor is not moving according to LRD inputs). Please help me with circuit diagram.

Here is the code I am using

```
const int dirPin  = 5;
const int stepPin = 4;
const int enPin   = 6;
const int SensorPin1 = A0;
const int SensorPin2 = A1;
int sensorValue1 = 0;
int sensorValue2 = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(enPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enPin,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600); 

}
void loop() {
  sensorValue1 = analogRead(SensorPin1); 
  Serial.println(sensorValue1);
  sensorValue2 = analogRead(SensorPin2); 
  Serial.println(sensorValue2);

  if(sensorValue1 < 40 && sensorValue2 < 400){
    Serial.print("No sun Detected");
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
  }
  else if(sensorValue1 > 400){

    digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);

 }
else if(sensorValue2 > 400){
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
}
}
```

**Hardware Used:**

- Bipolar stepper motor- NEMA 23 20Kg torque
- Stepper driver: TB6600
- Power supply: SMPS 12V, 5amp
- LDR: 2
- Resistors: 2, 10K resistors
- 1 Arduino Uno
- Breadboard

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: With most stepper drivers the stepper will move 1 (!) step when you put 1 pulse on the input (meaning a transition low-high-low or invers). Your code will at most drive the motor 1 step, most likely not enough to see it. Generate more pulses

Comment: Change `digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);` to `digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);delay(1);digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);`

Comment: Thanks @chrisl ..will try and let you know...but I am still looking for circuit digram

Comment: For the circuit diagram: Have you seen for example [this User Guide on the TB6600](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1t7C798ThAhUSsaQKHV43CqIQFjAGegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dfrobot.com%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%2FTB6600_Stepper_Motor_Driver_SKU%3A_DRI0043&usg=AOvVaw3StPPcyHQy8k_v1Gerphcl)? There it is mentioned, how the driver has to be connected to the Arduino and to the motor. You can even download the more detailed user guide as pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I tuned your code little.

```
const int dirPin  = 8;
const int stepPin = 7;
const int enPin   = 13;//with pin 13 You can monitor on-board LED, if its lit, "enable" is HIGH and stepper will turn.
const int rightSensorPin = A0;
const int leftSensorPin = A1;
int rightSensorRead = 0;
int leftSensorRead = 0;
int rightLightPct = 0;
int leftLightPct = 0;
int degreeChange = 1;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT_PULLUP);//no need extra resistors. Just connect one LDR leg to A0 and another GND.
  pinMode(A1, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  rightSensorRead = analogRead(rightSensorPin);
  leftSensorRead = analogRead(leftSensorPin);
  rightLightPct = map(rightSensorRead, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
  leftLightPct = map(leftSensorRead, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
  degreeChange = map(abs(rightLightPct-leftLightPct),0,100,2,10);
  Serial.print("right = ");
  Serial.print(rightSensorRead);
  Serial.print(" left = ");
  Serial.print(leftSensorRead);
  Serial.print(" Pct r/l = ");
  Serial.print(rightLightPct);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.println(leftLightPct);
  if(rightLightPct < 15 && leftLightPct < 15){
    Serial.println("Sun is detected");
    digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delay(5000);//if somthing get in a way, program waits 5 sec. If nothing in that time, program will continue. That time may erase or add some more.
  }else if(rightLightPct > 50 && leftLightPct > 50){
    Serial.println("Sun is set!");
    digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
  }else if(rightLightPct > 20 && leftLightPct > 20){
    Serial.println("Seeking sun!");
    digitalWrite(enPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
  }else if(rightLightPct > leftLightPct){
    Serial.println("Turning CW!");
    digitalWrite(enPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
  }else{
    Serial.println("Turning CCW!");
    digitalWrite(enPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delay(1);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
  }
}
```